# $('#fileupload').fileupload function is not calling

Tags: jquery, blueimp

I am configuring blueimp to upload image on click to post button. My problem is it is not calling the `$('#fileupload').fileupload` function. I have included following javascript files. The following is my code please see what is the problem.

```
<head>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jQuery-File-Upload-master/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jQuery-File-Upload-master/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jQuery-File-Upload-master/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript">
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType : 'json',
            url : "ownmessages",
            add: function (e, data) {
                $('#post') .click(function () {
                    $('#post').text('Uploading...');
                    data.submit();
                });
            },
            done: function (e, data) {
                $('#post').text('Upload finished.');
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <s:form action="ownmessages" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <s:textarea rows="2" cols="40" name="message" id="message1"></s:textarea><br>
        <s:select name="msg_visibility" id="msg_visibility" list="#{'public':'Public', 'friends':'Friends','me':'Me only'}" value="public"/>
        <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="user_post_image[]"  data-url="ownmessages"/>
        <input type="button" value="Post" id="post" />
    </s:form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wait for the document to finish loading before you try and select any elements.  The jQuery `.ready()` method waits for the Document Object Model (DOM) to finish loading and then runs your script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType : 'json',
        url : "ownmessages",
        add: function (e, data) {
            $('#post') .click(function () {
                $('#post').text('Uploading...');
                data.submit();
            });
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            $('#post').text('Upload finished.');
        }
    });
});
```

Instead of using `.ready()` you can also just pass a function to jQuery.

```
$(function() {
    // will run after DOM is loaded
});
```

Comment: +1 for the shorted version of `jQuery.ready`. You can even make a local version of the `$` by using the first argument in the ready callback: `jQuery(function($) { /* in here $ mos def equals to jQuery */ });`

Comment: I added $(document).ready(function() { but still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

first problem :

---

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType : 'json',
        url : "ownmessages",
        add: function (e, data) {
            $('#post') .click(function () {
                $('#post').text('Uploading...');
                data.submit();
            });
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            $('#post').text('Upload finished.');
        }
    });
   });
</script>
```

that's a beginning but might not be enough...

next for the sake of optimization at least, move your script tags to the bottom

Comment: you look in yur console to see if there is a js error, then you use console.log(vartocheck) at each step to see where the problem is coming from